# C program to calculate largest gap between prime numbers in a range

Tags: c, primes

can anyone help me write this program ? even a pseudo code will do the job.
this program should scan a number like 34 and calculate the largest gap between prime numbers before 34, I mean (29-23-1)=5.
thank you so much

```
int y,x,N,large=3,small=2,b,a;

scanf("%d",&N);

    for(y=3;y<N;++y)
        for(x=2;x<y;++x)
            a=y%x;

    if(a==0) break;

    else if(y>large && y>small) small=large;

    large=y;small=x;b=large-small-1;

    if(b<large-small-1)b=large-small-1;

    printf("%d",b);
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not how Stack Overflow works.  Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your program does not contain a `main`. Is there anything else wrong about it?

Comment: You need to ask a clear and specific question. "help me write this program" is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can anyone help me write this program ?

Well, that is *a clear and specific question.* But instead of answering "Yes.", I'll show the little rearrangement that your try needed, with explanations in comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int y, x, N, large=2, small, b=0, a;    // don't forget to initialize b
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (y=3; y<N; ++y)
        for (x=2; x<y; ++x)
        {
            a=y%x;
            if (a==0) break;

            if (x*x < y) continue;      // continue if unsure whether y is prime

            small=large;
            large=y;
            if (b<large-small)
                b=large-small;
            break;                      // we handled this prime y, go to next y
        }
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```